# Migrating Zxing blazor from Blazor wasm app to Blazor Hybrid app

Tags: blazor, zxing, blazor-webassembly, .net-maui, blazor-hybrid

i was using  Zxing.blazor for scan QR code , but in .NET maui , they ask me for permission ,and i have no idea how to access this permission
PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: *this permission*: what is the exact message given, or permission name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it say permission denied

Comment: @Community i was using ZxingBlazor to scan Qr codes in my blazor web assembly app when i migrate to Blazor hybrid , i copy the same code hope it will work , but it doesn't , i get an error message "Permission denied" , hope it's clear , else please let me know ,thank you !!